# How to save HashMap<String, Parcelable> to file?

Tags: android, parcelable, objectoutputstream, instancestate

Sorry for my poor English.

I have a `HashMap<String, Parcelable>` to save some `InstanceState`s of a `RecyclerView`,and I want to save the `HashMap<String, Parcelable>` into a **file**.

I use the `ObjectOutputStream`,it can write into a file,but when I use `ObjectInputStream`,it seems that it doesn't have read some useful data,because the state of the `RecyclerView` doesn't change to the state that has been saved.

Why this doesn't work?

How can I save and restore `InstanceState` of view by **"key-value"**???

I want to save `InstanceState`  **permanently**.

Thank you for your help~

my code:

```
private HashMap <String, Parcelable> hmRecyclerViewState = new HashMap<String, Parcelable>();    
private Parcelable recyclerViewState;
ObjectOutputStream oos;
ObjectInputStream ois;
```

1.

```
    try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(stateFile));
        hmRecyclerViewState = (HashMap<String, Parcelable>)ois.readObject();
    } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OptionalDataException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {  
        if (ois != null) {  
            try {  
                ois.close();  
            } catch (IOException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        }
    }
```

2.

```
    try {
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(stateFile));
        if (hmRecyclerViewState != null)
            oos.writeObject(hmRecyclerViewState);
        oos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {  
        try {  
            if (oos != null)  
                oos.close();  
        } catch (IOException ex) {  
            ex.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }
```

3.

```
public void saveRecyclerViewState(String tableName) {
    recyclerViewState = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
    hmRecyclerViewState.put(tableName, recyclerViewState);
}
```

4.

```
public void restoreRecyclerViewState(String tableName) {
    if ( hmRecyclerViewState.get(tableName) != null) {
        recyclerViewState = hmRecyclerViewState.get(tableName);
        recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState);
        recyclerViewState = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can iterate on it and save it a file...

Comment: @sourabhbans thanks.But what does "iterate on it" mean?Can you show some code please?

Answer (score 0):

You can save **Parcelable objects** to the **String** or **XML** or **JSON** type. And then you can save them to files. By the way, the HashMap Object implements the Serializable, so you can save HashMap Object to file without any problems.

There are some informations about [**PARCELABLE VS. JAVA SERIALIZATION IN ANDROID APP DEVELOPMENT**](http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/parcelable-vs-java-serialization-in-android-app-development)

Comment: thanks,but I don't understand how to **save Parcelable objects to the String** ? I save instancestate in a Parcelable object.Can you show some code?Very thanks

Answer (score 0):

If i followed your question than you can do something like..
Iterate over your map >> put into a String builder >> save it into file.
In your case create a toString() method in your parcelable class that returns all fields like(id,name,address...) in a format like comma separated.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Map.Entry<String, Parcelable> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Parcelable value = entry.getValue();
   // append it to String builder
    sb.append(key+":"value.toString()+"\n");
}
// write here to a file..
```

and when you want to restore read from file >> put it into Map >> restore it.

Comment: When I restore it, how can I transfer the `value.toString()` to the `Parcelable` object ? Sorry, I am new.

Comment: you can set the values to object using setter methods of your bean class.

Comment: the object is not customed by me, it is from `recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState()` which returns a `Parcelable` object, I open the source code, it is an Interface. I don't how to do it?